# EXCEL: Counting worksheets dynamically using INDIRECT

Tags: excel, excel-indirect

I've come across several discussions on using INDIRECT and 3D references, however none seem to address (or fix) this problem specifically.

I'm trying to count the position of a worksheet without using VBA. Each sheet represents a month, and has a standardized name (e.g. JAN-15, FEB-15, MAR-15, etc.). My idea is to find the position by counting the number of sheets between JAN-15 and the current sheet. A1 of each sheet = 1, which gets summed across the sheets using a 3D reference.

Using February as an example, I can hard code this with no problem:

=SUM('JAN-15:FEB-15'!A1)

When I do this, I get the expected result of 2. However, I want each month's sheet to dynamically generate its position without having to change the formula each time. So I tried this:

Cell named FIRSTMONTH ='JAN-15
Cell named CURRMONTH =RIGHT(CELL("FILENAME",A1),6)
N1 =CONCATENATE("'",FIRSTMONTH,":",CURRMONTH,"'!A1")
(N1 evaluates correctly as 'JAN-15:FEB-15'!A1)

When I try this formula to generate the position:

=SUM(INDIRECT(N1))

I get a #REF! error. I've also tried this variation:

=SUM(INDIRECT("N1"))

Which returns 0.

Anyone have an idea of how I can get this to work? Or is there a better way that doesn't use VBA?

-David

Comment: I should also mention that I'm using Excel 2011 for Mac. I noticed that Excel 2013 has a handy SHEET() function that basically does exactly what I want...

Comment: You can't use INDIRECT to "build" a 3d formula - I assume you have sheets over several years (or start month might not be Jan) otherwise it would be sufficient to use the month number to get position

Comment: Each year gets its own workbook, and each starts with JAN, so your DATEDIF solution works perfectly. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you won't have any gaps perhaps try counting the number of month between the first month and the current one, e.g.

`=DATEDIF(FIRSTMONTH,CURRMONTH,"m")+1`